# Dictionary/HashTable Object in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm looking for a HashTable or Dictionary implementation in C++ that has similar functionality to the one in C#? Does the STL contain an object like this and how would I use it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, to be exactly the same as .NET's Dictionary/Hashtable, what you want is [hash_map](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.1/class____gnu__cxx_1_1hash__map.html) or [unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) (`std::map` is implemented as a binary tree),  `hash_map` is an extension to the SC++L. Most compilers that I know of come with `hash_map`, though, and boost obviously has `unordered_map` until C++0x is available in all compilers, so you should just be able to use it without trouble.

Comment: C++ has no such container as hash_map,, and won't in C++0x. The name of the name of the hash table in C++ is unordered_map - se http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v9v111/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp9.aix.doc/standlib/stl_unordered_map.htm

Comment: Ahh, the C++ standards process. Bickering about the name of a hashtable class while Rome burns.

Answer (score 5):

STL has [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Comment: map is a balanced tree, not a hash container.

Comment: @joe - question was for a hashmap *or* dictionary class in c++ STL, so `std::map` fits the bill.

Comment: @gnud: OP also said "that has similar functionality to the one in C#", which only unordered_map fits, if you're talking about performance characteristics.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for `map`.  See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) for more.

Answer (score 2):

The STL `std::map` can be used to build a dictionary. `std::map` is usually implemented as a search tree, not a hash table. That means both lookup and insertion has different perfomance characteristics than C#'s `HashMap` - for very large maps, average lookup will be slower, especially if the objects in the map are fragmented in memory.

In the TR1 of the new c++ standard, you have `std::tr1::unordered_map` and `std::tr1::unordered_multimap`, which will usually be implemented using a hash table. If your compiler does not provide those libraries, you can use the implementation from http://www.boost.org/.

Yet another alternative is Google's [`sparse_hash`](http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/).

Comment: A lookup in an std::map is **not** per se slower than in a hash_map.  Only the asymptotical performance of a hash_map is O(1) vs. O(log n), but for big enough values of 1, log n may be faster.  Even practically this is often enough the case, _and_ finding a good hash-function is much more difficult than implementing a correct operator<.

Comment: Just re-read, you said _often_, not always, my fault.  However, _often_ implies that most often people use dictionaries with, well, more than about 1000 entries, using correct hash-functions.  Depending on area of work and the skill level within a company this may indeed be unlikely.

Comment: Maybe 'will often be slower' isa bit harsh. My point is mainly that they have different performance characteristics.

Comment: There is also [MCT's closed_hash_map](https://launchpad.net/libmct) similar to Google's `dense_hash_map` but without the restriction on keys.